# Why push stack first subtracts from stack pointer then inserts data?

Tags: stack

I was wondering why the push instruction first subtracts and then inserts the data.

With this implementation, the stack pointer points to the last data pushed. Even though this is generally not a problem, I would argue that since at the beginning of the program there are no valid data in stack, it makes more sense to first insert and then decrease the stack pointer.

Why this:

```
sub  $8,%rsp        # subtract 8 from rsp
mov  reg,(%rsp)     # store, using rsp as the address
```

and not this:

```
mov  reg,(%rsp)     # store, using rsp as the address
sub  $8,%rsp        # subtract 8 from rsp
```

Is there a particular reason why they chose this order of operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example in 32bit x86 architecture you can push different size values into stack. There is no way to know beforehand what size value you want to push so the pointer cannot be moved beforehand, in this case after the store.

So let's say you would have this code:

```
PUSH EAX
PUSH BX
PUSH ECX
```

If we first store and then subtract we get this (let's say ESP is 100 and ignore possible issues with ESP/SP mix use):

```
MOV EAX, (%ESP) // EAX -> 100..103
SUB %ESP, 4 // ESP = 96
MOV BX, (%SP) // BX -> 96..97
SUB %SP, 2. // ESP = 94
MOV ECX, (%RSP) // ECX -> 94..97
SUB %RSP, 4 // ESP = 90
```

See how the subtraction uses the *previous* size always for the next one. This means that pushing BX would first cause two unused bytes to be in the stack and then pushing ECX would actually *overwrite* the value of BX in the stack. When doing the subtraction first it always uses the size of the *current* value being pushed to the stack:

```
SUB %ESP, 4 // ESP = 96
MOV EAX, (%ESP) // EAX -> 96..99
SUB %SP, 2. // ESP = 94
MOV BX, (%SP) // BX -> 94..95
SUB %RSP, 4 // ESP = 90
MOV ECX, (%RSP) // ECX -> 90..93
```

Now nothing is overwritten, no gaps happen and everyone's happy.

This of course assumes the stack grows downwards, like it usually does. If the stack was going upwards then the addition would be after the store to keep the addresses proper.

In x64 mode it would be simpler since values are (to my knowledge) always pushed as 8 byte blocks.

Also other architectures may allow different kinds of pushes so having the pointer moved on push before storing the data results in the most versatile operation.

Comment: @AntonisParagas No, in 32bit mode it can only push 2 or 4 byte values.

Comment: I didn't get how the 32bit x86 would have had problem with the second approach. When you are pushing 16bits the opcode for push is different than the opcode when pushing 32bit (immediates). So the CPU does know what is the size.

Comment: @AntonisParagas But the subtraction happens based on the previous value. I'll add an explanation.

Comment: @AntonisParagas Added the explanation

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i had messed the stack addressing.